# Neural network with dependencies between features

Tags: multidimensional-array, neural-network, linear-regression, numpy-ndarray

here is my issue:

I Have shape create by coordinates before and after a rotation. I am trying to create a neural network with linear regression as output. X1 (x1, y1) and X2(x2, y2) are my input (features) and y_train represents the angle between shape X1 and X2. X_train is a stack of X1 and X2.
here what i have tried:

```
python
print('shape X1:', np.shape(X1))
print('shape X2:', np.shape(X2))
shape X1:(XXX, 2, 120)
shape X2:(XXX, 2, 120)

print('shape X_train:', np.shape(X_train))
shape X: (XXX, 2, 2, 120)

print('shape y:', np.shape(y_train))
shape X: (XXX, 1)

# Model definition
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(X_train.shape[0], input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3]), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))
```

Then when I try to train the model with :

```
                                      
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer= tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics='mse')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=500, validation_split=0.3, verbose=1)
```

I have this issue:

""" InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [32,2,2,1] vs. [32,1]
[[node gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined at :16) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_310234] """

It is working when I add model.Flatten(), but i don't want to use it cause X1 and X2 will be "mixed"...

Does someone have the solution ?  :-)